# Append html template in message property of titanium alert dialog

Tags: appcelerator-titanium

I am new in appcelerator. I want to insert html template in message property of alert dialog. When add message as a string it's working fine but i want to insert html template. what i tried so far mention bellow, but its not working.

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
  backgroundColor:'#F00'
});

var mybutton=Ti.UI.createButton
(
  {top: 100,title: 'Push Me'}
);

win1.add(mybutton);

var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
  title:'Alert Test',
  message:'Hello World'
});

Ti.API.info('Alert title: ' + a.getTitle() + ' : ' + a.title);
Ti.API.info('Alert message: ' + a.getMessage()  + ' : ' + a.message);

mybutton.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
  a.show();
}
);

win1.open();
```

I want to show below template in alert dialog
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator is not an HTML-based environment, like PhoneGap. Appcelerator/Titanium exposes native controls in a JavaScript environment. You can't do what you want natively (the UIAlert/Alert classes support text, not HTML). So, you can't do that in Titanium. Spend a little time reading the docs and checking out the samples you'll find there.

To create the screen you show in your question, you'll need to create a View containing Labels, TextFields, TextAreas, and Buttons. I know, that probably sounds like all HTML stuff. But it's not, those will be representations of native components.